# How to tied bottom of the Image to the bottom of Text in Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have **Image** and **Text**.

Text has specified *fontSize* **30.sp** and top *padding* **25.dp**
How to make **Image** having no paddings, but bottom of the **Image** should be tied to bottom of the **Text**?

So that **Image** wouldn't appear below **Text** and by changing the height of **Text** would have similar impact on positioning of **Image**.

[image]

Comment: Put the 2 in a row and specify ```verticalAlignment = Alignment.Bottom```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to combine them in a Row and set the Verticle Alignment like below

```
Row(verticalAlignment = Alignment.Bottom) {
    Image(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.img_sample), contentDescription = "")
    Text(text = "A SAMPLE TEXT")
}
```